# SIFT implemetion the returns a single vector for the entire image

Tags: computer-vision, sift

I'm trying to use SIFT (from opencv) to get a histogram that describes an image. The problem is, that SIFT identifies a lot of points of interest in the image and gives me a 128 elements vector. While It seems to me as this is what SIFT supposed to do, my lab's PI told me there is an implementation that gives a single 128 elements vector for the all image. Do you know of such an implementation ?

If not, is there any other way of getting a good descriptor for an image ?
(for the purpose of machine learning classification)

Answer (score 0):

In SIFT descriptors feature extraction, each keypoints/interest points gives a 128D SIFT features and as there are multiple keypoints in an image, you will get some 128D x No. of keypoints SIFT vectors for each image. As per my experience, if you try to use SIFT features extraction in OpenCV, you will have to build the library from scratch as SIFT is patented algorithm, the OpenCV community have removed the plug-in library for SIFT and SURF.
You can also try other feature extraction techniques like VLAD, Fisher vector, RGB color histogram, HoG (Histogram of Oriented Gradient) features.